# jquery to have animated popup

Tags: jquery, popup, animated

In my main page, I need to have a main links displayed...and on mouse hover of each main link it should display a layer (something like modal popup but a smooth one)...and in the layer user should be able to select other links.

It should allow the user to move smoothly between the main links.

Can I use jQuery for this? If not what should I use?

Comment: 16 questions and zero answers accepted! Anish, in case you are not aware: that's bad manners.

Comment: I donno wher's the link to accept.. I'm sorry I apologise.

Comment: When you go back and look at a question you've asked, the answers will have a big check mark at the left side of the page. When you see an answer that you really like (one that answers the question the best), click that check mark.

Comment: Click on your name.  You will see the list of questions.  For each question, Click the question title.  Read the given answers.  Click the checkmark next to the best answer.  Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Jquery Tooltip plugin like the following

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip#Demos